# Replace function requires 3 arguments

Tags: sql, sql-server, excel, replace, parameter-passing

I am trying to fetch data from SQL to excel and it is giving me the below error
My Query in SQL Server

```
DECLARE @Delimiter Char(1)

SET @Delimiter = CHAR(9)

EXEC MSDB.dbo.sp_Send_DBMail
        @profile_name = 'K2MailSetup',        
        @Recipients='abs@test.com',        
        @Subject='Extraction Report',        
        @Body='Hi,
        Please find attached extraction report as required. ',        
        @Query='set nocount on;Select Coalesce(replace(replace(A.[type], char(10), ''), char(13), ''),'') as Type FROM [EU_OTH_REG].[dbo].[TBL_EU_OTH_TXN_REG_RSDS] A',
        @Attach_Query_Result_As_File = 1,        
        @Query_Result_Header = 1,        
        @Query_Attachment_Filename = 'Report.csv',        
        @Query_Result_Separator = @Delimiter,           
        @query_result_width =32767,
        @query_result_no_padding=1
```

========================================================================

It is giving me below error

```
Msg 22050, Level 16, State 1, Line 0
Error formatting query, probably invalid parameters
Msg 14661, Level 16, State 1, Procedure sp_send_dbmail, Line 517
Query execution failed: Msg 105, Level 15, State 1, Server MYKULK2DB01Q\MSSQLSTG, Line 1
Unclosed quotation mark after the character string ') as Type

            FROM [EU_OTH_REG].[dbo].[TBL_EU_OTH_TXN_REG_RSDS] A
'.
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Server MYKULK2DB01Q\MSSQLSTG, Line 1
Incorrect syntax near ') as Type

            FROM [EU_OTH_REG].[dbo].[TBL_EU_OTH_TXN_REG_RSDS] A
```

========================================================================

The strange thing is that when I just run the query it provides me result but when I try to create report out of it by using the above excel steps and parameters it gives me error.

Comment: Please consider going through docs: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/replace-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: There are a bunch of quotes in your `@Query` value, you need to escape those.

Comment: When debugging dynamic like this you should evaluate the dynamic sql you generate using print. It will isolate the syntax errors quickly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to check the quote in the **@Query** variable.
I replaced it in the following;

`@Query='set nocount on;Select Coalesce(replace(replace(A.[type], char(10), ''''), char(13), ''''),'''') as Type FROM [EU_OTH_REG].[dbo].[TBL_EU_OTH_TXN_REG_RSDS] A'`

Answer (score 0):

From the docs: [SQL Server Replace](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/replace-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)

The syntax for REPLACE() goes as follows:

```
REPLACE ( string_expression , string_pattern , string_replacement )
```

As you can see, all parameters should be in string format. Make sure all parameters are encased in `''` for your script to work.